# Javascript preventing input files from submitting to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="pbd1" class="photbox">
        <input id="ph1" name="img1" type="file" hidden>
    </div>
    <div id="pbd2" class="photbox">
        <input id="ph2" name="img2" type="file" hidden>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
for (let a = 1; a < 3; a++) {
    $("#pbd"+a).click(function(e) {
        $(this).children("#ph"+a).click();
    });
    $('#ph'+a).click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#ph'+a).on('change', function(e){
        var files = e.target.files;
        $.each(files, function(i, file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function(e){
                template = 
                '<div class="photbox">'+
                    '<input id="ph'+a+'" name="img'+a+'" type="file" hidden>'+
                    '<img class="blah" src="'+e.target.result+'">'+
                '</div>';
                $('#pbd'+a).replaceWith(template);
            };
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

What my code does: User clicks on `div id="pbd1"`, it triggers a click on `input id="ph1"`, which throws a dialog window requesting user to select a file from their computer. Once user has selected a file, a thumbnail image of that file is displayed. This is all worked by my javascript code. But my issue - this javascript somehow affects the uploaded file from being inserted into my database. My goal: to *insert* the uploaded files to my database. So I'm stuck and not sure how to fix this. Please help

EDIT: People are suggesting that it's an issue with my server. It is not because I am able to successfully submit this form doing it this way:

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="clickme1" hidden>
<input type="file" name="img2" id="clickme2" hidden>
<span id="sp1">CLICKME1</span>
<span id="sp2">CLICKME2</span>
<span id="here1"></span>
<span id="here2"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sp1").click(function(e) {
    $("#clickme1").click();
});
$("#sp2").click(function(e) {
    $("#clickme2").click();
});
document.getElementById('clickme1').onchange = function (evt) {
    $this = $(this).val();
    f = $this.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
    $("#here1").text(f);
};
document.getElementById('clickme2').onchange = function (evt) {
    $this = $(this).val();
    f = $this.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
    $("#here2").text(f);
};
</script>
```

But I cannot use this on my overall code. I need to use the "javascript thumbnail code" shown first. But it somehow is affecting the files from being inserted into the database.

Comment: So is the file being uploaded successfully? Check your browser inspector's network panel to find out. If it isn't, what is being posted? If it is, you have a server-side problem and you haven't included any server-side code.

Comment: @miken32 I didn't think I needed to include the php code because I assumed it was mostly the javascript affecting it. However I am able to successfully submit this form to the database. I have 3 columns on my database table - `imgid` (primary key field), `img1` (for `input id="img1"`) and `img2` (for `input id="img2"`). So when form is submitted, only the primary key gets autoincremented, but the values for columns `img1` and `img2` remain empty. That is the issue, there is no problem with my server-side

Comment: @misner3456 *"I didn't think I needed to include the php code because I assumed it was mostly the javascript affecting it."* .. Wht makes you sure it is a JavaScript problem? when this issue happens are you sure the file, and data have not been sent to the server ?

Comment: if you remove the code that shows the thumbnail, does the file upload work? by the way, you're using jQuery wrong - no need to set things up in a loop like that

Comment: @Accountant Yeah I don't know how to tell if the file has been sent or not

Comment: browser developer tools network tab will show you

Comment: I see the possible issue with the thumbnail code

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, if I remove the "javascript thumbnail code" I am able to send this to the server. So if I'm using jquery wrong with the loop, how would you suggest I do it? The reason for the loop is to loop through both input files - there are 2, it is not just 1. I used this looping method because it makes for much shorter code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not seeing the issue through the network tab though? And what would you say the possible issue with the thumbnail code is? Thank you

Comment: the issue with the thumbnail code is the fact that you're replacing the input element with a new one - therefore, no file is selected anymore

Comment: as far as loop in your code making it shorter, that depends on how you use jQuery, and you don't use it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that your code is replacing the input element, therefore you lose the selected file

The following not only corrects that mistake, but (hopefully) shows how you can avoid the for loop (note the extra `class="inputFile"` for the input)

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="pbd1" class="photbox">
        <input id="ph1" name="img1" class="inputFile" type="file" hidden>
    </div>
    <div id="pbd2" class="photbox">
        <input id="ph2" name="img2" class="inputFile" type="file" hidden>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".photbox").click(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".inputFile").click();
});
$(".inputFile").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(".inputFile").on('change', function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var _this = this;
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        while(_this.nextElementSibling) _this.nextElementSibling.remove();
        img.className = 'blah';
        img.src = e.target.result;
        _this.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
</script>
```

I've also removed the `files` loop, since you seem to only want a single file (in each input) anyway

A, perhaps, cleaner version of the change handler

```
$(".inputFile").on('change', function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => { // this in here will be the input element
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        while(this.nextElementSibling) this.nextElementSibling.remove();
        img.className = 'blah';
        img.src = e.target.result;
        this.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking the time to rewrite my code, however this method only inserts one image to the database. If I wanted to upload 2 images, it would only insert the last clicked on image, but not both?

Comment: huh? so you DO want multiple files *in each input* ? - your attempted code would NEVER be able to do that, since you `replaceWith` in each iteration

Comment: ok I don't think I was clear on what I was asking. There are only 2 inputs, and whichever input is clicked on should upload the image. If both inputs are clicked on, then both files should be uploaded and both should be sent to the server. Not just 1. Only 1 image should be sent to database if only 1 of the inputs is clicked on and the submit button instantaneously clicked on. Sorry about that

Comment: yep, well this code handles that - hang on, minor revision to remove old image if you click to select a different one

Comment: Oh wow, you fixed my code! Your second method is definitely the more preferable way to go. And you were able to clean this without the messy inclusion of the forloop. Seriously, I cannot thank you enough. Thank you!!

Comment: I can show you a non-jquery answer too :p https://jsfiddle.net/vgfxzL62/ - no jQuery required at all :p

Comment: No, no you did way more than is enough already. I am amazed by how you perfectly formatted and cleaned the code. This is excellent, your skills are much appreciated here!!

Comment: Oh jeez, you are too generous haha thanks for the backup javascript :) I may need to use that for reference. You are too helpful, thank you so much!